# Mathematical operations on Mat objects OpenCv

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I want to rewrite C++ code to Java. I am using OpenCV4Android. Code in C++ looks like that

```
{
    double meanI = 0.0;
    {
        Mat tmp;
        pow(abs(I), alpha, tmp);
        meanI = mean(tmp).val[0];

    }
    I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);
}

{
    double meanI = 0.0;
    {
        Mat tmp;
        pow(min(abs(I), tau), alpha, tmp);
        meanI = mean(tmp).val[0];
    }
    I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);
}
```

I don't know how to make abs from OpenCV Mat object like that

```
abs(I)
```

I don't know how make a division of matrix and double number like that:

```
I = mat/double
```

Please help me

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

There is an equivalent that you can use in Java.
Instead of B=abs(A) you may use:

```
Core.absdiff(A, Scalar.all(0), B);
```

About per-element division you can use Core.divide()

```
Core.divide(A,Scalar.all(d), B);
```

It's equivalent to B=A/d

Answer (score -1):

- **For `abs()`**, you can use it as:

  ```
  cv::Mat Result = abs(I);
  ```
- **For `division by a scale`**, you can do

  ```
  cv::Mat Result = I / alpha;
  ```

  or:

  ```
  float beta = 1.0f / alpha;
  cv::Mat Result = I * beta;
  ```

Comment: OP wants to know how to rewrite it to Java.